# What to do if clicking the build button does not do anything in Sublime Text?

Tags: java, sublimetext, build-system

I am running a hello world code in java on Sublime text, and it is not doing anything. It is not giving me any kind of  output, including error messages. I an running it through a custom Java build system that I got from Youtube, that has worked for other people. This is my code:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I tried to run the code, expecting it to print Hello World in the output area, and nothing happened.

Comment: Use a proper IDE, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, use an IDE, another alternative to IntelliJ is Eclipse (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Hi there, you said you've tried to run the code, but how did you try? Can you talk about it also